# What is the best resource for learning about Safety Critical Systems Development (C/C++)

Tags: system, safety-critical

I'm looking to locate a good resource (book or otherwise) on safety critical systems development techniques/methodologies, especially something that will cover both hardware and software . I have a sound working knowledge of C/C++, so even if it is just code on SourceForge etc I would still appreciate a link to it to have a browse.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The podcast [Software Engineering Radio](http://se-radio.net/) has some episodes which talk about e.g. real-time and fault tolerant systems which I found very informative. Those episodes also had good references to books.

Comment: Oh wow, how did I not know about this podcast before :/