# HOW TO: Deep Copy of Linked List

Tags: c

I am having some issues with a program I am writing in C, and I have surpassed my knowledge. In summary, I need to deep copy a link list from one list to another. The lists have malloc'd data in them and I need to preserve all the data without having pointers pointing at the same information.

I have only posted the code that I think is relevant. If I am missing any important contextual information please let me know.

Here is the code:

#### matrix.h

```
typedef struct matrix {
        char *name;
        int R;
        int C;
        int dim;
        void (*concat_matrices)( struct matrix *A, struct matrix *B, struct matrix *ret );
} Matrix;

void concat_matrices( Matrix *A, Matrix *B, Matrix *ret ) {
        int L1 = strlen( A->name );
        int L2 = strlen( B->name );
        int len = L1 + L2;
        char *Ap = (char*)malloc(L1*sizeof(char)); strcpy(Ap,A->name);
        char *Bp = (char*)malloc(L2*sizeof(char )); strcpy(Bp,B->name);
        char *c = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len + 2));
        c[0] = '('; strcat(c, Ap); strcat(c, Bp); c[len+1] = ')';
        ret->name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len + 2));
        strcpy(ret->name, c);
        ret->R = A->R; ret->C = B->C;
        ret->dim = ret->R*ret->C;
        free(Ap); free(Bp); free(c);
}
```

#### matrix_list.h

```
typedef struct node {
        Matrix *M;
        struct node *next;
        struct node *prev;
} Node;

typedef struct matrix_list {
        Node *head;
        Node *tail;
        int size;
        void (*append)( struct matrix_list *list, Matrix *M );
        void (*print)( struct matrix_list *list );
        void (*reverse_print)( struct matrix_list *list );
        void (*delete)( struct matrix_list *list, const char *name );
        void (*delete_tail)( struct matrix_list *list );
        void (*delete_head)( struct matrix_list *list );
        void (*release)( struct matrix_list *list );
        void (*clone_list)( struct matrix_list *from, struct matrix_list *to );
} MatrixList;

...

void clone_list( MatrixList *from, MatrixList *to ) {
        if( from->head == NULL ) {
                to = NULL;
        } else {
                Node *tmp = from->head;
                while( tmp != NULL ) {
                        Matrix *m_copy = (Matrix*)malloc(sizeof(Matrix*));
                        char *c_copy = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*)*strlen(tmp->M->name));

                        strcpy(c_copy,tmp->M->name);
                        m_copy->name=c_copy;
                        m_copy->R=tmp->M->R;
                        m_copy->C=tmp->M->C;
                        m_copy->concat_matrices = concat_matrices;

                        to->append( to,m_copy );
                        tmp = tmp->next;
                }
        }
}
```

#### main.c

```
chain->print(chain);

MatrixList *chain_copy = (MatrixList*)malloc(sizeof(MatrixList));
set_list_functions( chain_copy );
chain->clone_list(chain, chain_copy);
chain_copy->print(chain_copy);
```

The problem arises when I try and print out the clone. Because I am malloc'ing in the clone function I understand the data goes out of scope. How can I do this copy so after the function is called clone has its own version of the data?

---

**UPDATE:**

First I would like to thank you all for taking your time to answer my question, and for teaching me more about C. I have only been coding for about 3 years. And I have a lot to learn. The updated source with 0 errors from Valgrind can be found at.

http://matthewh.me/Scripts/c++/matrix_chain/ for anyone else trying to figure out things like me. User = guest Password = guest. The clone_list function now looks like this.

```
void clone_list( MatrixList *from, MatrixList *to ) {
        if( from->head == NULL ) {
                to = NULL;
        } else {
                Node *tmp = from->head;
                while( tmp != NULL ) {
                        Matrix *m_copy = (Matrix*)malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
                        m_copy->name = (char*)malloc(strlen(tmp->M->name) + 1);

                        sprintf( m_copy->name, "%s", tmp->M->name );
                        m_copy->R=tmp->M->R;
                        m_copy->C=tmp->M->C;
                        m_copy->concat_matrices = concat_matrices;

                        to->append( to,m_copy );
                        tmp = tmp->next;
                }
        }
}
```

If anyone else sees anything else wrong and would like to add additional pointers please feel free to do so.

Comment: Presumably you get the error when inside the `print` function?  Can you provide the code for that, along with exact line that the error message corresponds to?  Ideally, you should run your code in a debugger, and tell us the values of all variables at the point of the crash.

Comment: Yes when it runs chain_copy->print(chain_copy) I get the following output


[mehoggan@desktop matrix_chain]$ ./main 
A B C D E F 
d� d� d� d� d� d� 

and sample output from valgrind:

A B C D E F 
==2340== Invalid write of size 4
==2340==    at 0x8048C24: clone_list (matrix_list.h:164)
==2340==    by 0x8048E76: main (main.c:63)
==2340==  Address 0x402856c is 0 bytes after a block of size 4 alloc'd
==2340==    at 0x400677E: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
==2340==    by 0x8048BDA: clone_list (matrix_list.h:159)
==2340==    by 0x8048E76: main (main.c:63)

That print is from chain->print(chain);

Comment: Dear crap in heaven, *why* are you mallocing two arrays, copying `A->name` and `B->name` into them, mallocing another array, copying the two copies into that, and then mallocing *another* array to copy the last buffer into, *especially when you know how much space you'll need for the last array at the start of the function*?  This won't solve your immediate problem, but for the love of good practice, just malloc *one* array and copy everything into that!

Comment: Fixed the double malloc, wasn't sure if I could do that, since the strings I passed in were char* and not null terminated strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't allowed for the null that terminates strings, so you have classic buffer overflows.

You also do not need to copy the names *three* times.  Your current code is:

```
int L1 = strlen( A->name );
int L2 = strlen( B->name );
int len = L1 + L2;
char *Ap = (char*)malloc(L1*sizeof(char)); strcpy(Ap,A->name);
char *Bp = (char*)malloc(L2*sizeof(char )); strcpy(Bp,B->name);
char *c = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len + 2));
c[0] = '('; strcat(c, Ap); strcat(c, Bp); c[len+1] = ')';
ret->name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len + 2));
strcpy(ret->name, c);
ret->R = A->R; ret->C = B->C;
ret->dim = ret->R*ret->C;
free(Ap); free(Bp); free(c);
```

This should be:

```
int   L1 = strlen(A->name);
int   L2 = strlen(B->name);

ret->name = (char *)malloc(L1 + L2 + sizeof("()"));  // That adds 3
sprintf(ret->name, "(%s%s)", A->name, B->name);

ret->R   = A->R;
ret->C   = B->C;
ret->dim = ret->R * ret->C;
```

This eliminates `Ap`, `Bp` and `c` altogether, and avoids the buffer overflow problems.  I'm not sure I'd slam the two names together like you do, but that's your choice.

---

Apparently, this isn't sufficient of a problem...there are other issues too.

```
void clone_list( MatrixList *from, MatrixList *to ) {
    if (from->head == NULL) {
        to = NULL;
    } else {
        Node *tmp = from->head;
        while( tmp != NULL ) {
            Matrix *m_copy = (Matrix*)malloc(sizeof(Matrix*));
            char *c_copy = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*)*strlen(tmp->M->name));

            strcpy(c_copy,tmp->M->name);
            m_copy->name=c_copy;
            m_copy->R=tmp->M->R;
            m_copy->C=tmp->M->C;
            m_copy->concat_matrices = concat_matrices;

            to->append( to,m_copy );
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
    }
}
```

The first assignment zeroes the local pointer; it doesn't do a thing to the `MatrixList` passed in as the target.  This should presumably be:

```
if (from->head == 0)
{
    *to = *from;
}
```

This does a wholesale structure copy, but sets the head and tail to null, and the function pointers are all fine - they can be shared.  Assuming that the `size` in `from` was correctly zero, it will be correct in `to` too.  (Again, this is probably not the code you are exercising.)

The next problem is with the memory allocation:

```
Matrix *m_copy = (Matrix*)malloc(sizeof(Matrix*));
```

This allocates one pointer's worth of memory, not one Matrix's worth.  Use either of these:

```
Matrix *m_copy = (Matrix *)malloc(sizeof(*m_copy));
Matrix *m_copy = (Matrix *)malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
```

That is a major source of your trouble (and one which [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) will find easily).

---

When the `+1` gets forgotten once, it gets forgotten many times, but this time it doesn't cause problems unless the name is the empty string because you multiply by 4 or 8 (32-bit or 64-bit) because of the `sizeof(char *)` instead of the intended `sizeof(char)`.

```
char *c_copy = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*)*strlen(tmp->M->name));
strcpy(c_copy,tmp->M->name);
```

This should probably be:

```
m_copy->name = (char *)malloc(strlen(tmp->M->name) + 1);
strcpy(m_copy->name, tmp->M->name);
```

I'd probably use a name like `old` instead of `tmp`.  I am also remiss in not reminding previously that you should religiously check every return from every memory allocation.  Or use a set of cover functions for the memory allocation routines which do the check for you (often called `xmalloc()` or `emalloc()`, etc.).

The code below that does not seem to copy the `dim` member across, which is a bug if you ever depend on it.

I'm not entirely happy that you seem to rely on the `to` list being appropriately initializes before calling `clone_list()`.  In particular, the `head`, `tail` and `size` members are not zeroed here, and the function pointers are not set.  I'd be happier to see something like:

```
*to = *from;  // Copy function pointers
to->head = 0;
to->tail = 0;
to->size = 0;
Node *old = from->head;
for (Node *old = from->head; old != NULL; old = old->next)
{
    Matrix *m_copy = clone_matrix(old->M);
    to->append(to, m_copy);
}
```

Or even:

```
matrixlist_initialize(to);
Node *old = from->head;
for (Node *old = from->head; old != NULL; old = old->next)
{
    Matrix *m_copy = clone_matrix(old->M);
    to->append(to, m_copy);
}
```

The `clone_matrix()` function looks like:

```
Matrix *clone_matrix(const Matrix *old)
{
    Matrix *m_copy = (Matrix*)malloc(sizeof(*m_copy));

    m_copy->name = (char*)malloc(strlen(old->name)+1);

    strcpy(m_copy->name, old->name);
    m_copy->R   = old->R;
    m_copy->C   = old->C;
    m_copy->dim = old->dim;
    m_copy->concat_matrices = concat_matrices;
    return(m_copy);
}
```

---

I downloaded a version your code and it now seems to work, more or less.  You should be compiling with at least `-Wall` as a compiler option; I refuse to compile with anything less and usually use `-Wextra` too.  I make too many simple-to-spot mistakes not to make full use of the compiler, and while you are learning, you will too.  (I've only been coding in C for just over a quarter century; the compiler still catches typos and other silly mistakes, but I seldom have big problems once the code is compiling.)

When I turned on `-Wall`, there was a problem with the (unused) `perm()` function because it doesn't return a value even though it says it will, and there was a problem because the correct definition for `main()` with arguments is `int main(int argc, char **argv)` and you were missing one of the stars.  Other than that, it seems to be working OK now - you can continue with your development.

There is a function in POSIX called `strdup()` which duplicates a string reliably.  It is useful and avoids the off-by-one mistakes.

You should review the use of [headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804486/should-i-use-include-in-headers/1804719#1804719).  They are for declarations, primarily.  If you explicitly use `inline` (your code doesn't yet), it can be appropriate to include `inline` functions in a header, but otherwise, function bodies should not be in headers.  They should be in source files (`.c` suffix).  Each header should contain the minimum necessary information for the code that uses the functionality provided by the source to use.  It should not include extraneous headers, but it should include all necessary headers.  In `matrix.h`, you include `<stdio.h>` which is unnecessary.  And if you removed the code, neither `<string.h>` nor `<stdlib.h>` would be needed either.

Comment: Nice use of `sizeof("()")` to get the `'\0'` byte too.

Comment: Very nice indeed, but this is pulling me away from the original question. Any feed back on the original question is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Matthew: once you invoke undefined behaviour, what the rest of your program does is uncontrolled.  I'll take a look at the later parts, too, but this is one of the problems.  If you're on Linux, use [`valgrind`](http://www.valgrind.org/) to see whether there are other problems too.  The chances are that there are others as well.

Comment: Thank you, I will keep working on that. If you want the complete source follow this link (http://matthewh.me/Scripts/c++/matrix_chain/). Password = guest user = guest will give you read privileges to download. As I posted below my specific problem involves the clone_list function posted above in matrix_list.h.

Comment: @Jonathan: I ran val grind with the call to clone_list removed and valgrind reports no other issues using the following command.

==2420== 
==2420== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2420==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2420==   total heap usage: 20 allocs, 20 frees, 328 bytes allocated
==2420== 
==2420== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==2420== 
==2420== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2420== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 12 from 8)

Comment: valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full ./main

Comment: Thanks again for the input, made the changes moving the functions to .c files only leaving the structs in the headers etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
    int L1 = strlen( A->name );
    int L2 = strlen( B->name );
    int len = L1 + L2;
    char *Ap = (char*)malloc(L1*sizeof(char)); strcpy(Ap,A->name);
    char *Bp = (char*)malloc(L2*sizeof(char )); strcpy(Bp,B->name);
```

I'm willing to bet that your `strcpy(3)` calls here have written outside the bounds of the memory you've allocated: `strlen(3)` does NOT account for the `'\0'` terminator at the end of C strings, so your `*Ap` and `*Bp` are allocated one-byte-too-short.

Because this is *so* common it is an easy pattern to find bugs:

```
int len = strlen(s);
char *new = malloc(len); /* FAIL */
```

If I don't see a `+ 1` in the `malloc(3)` call, it's almost certainly a bug. :) I prefer to see:

```
int len = strlen(s);
char *new = malloc(len + 1);
```

rather than:

```
int len = strlen(s) + 1;
char *new = malloc(len);
```

If you follow the former, I think it is far easier to spot the *wrong* cases when you forget the `+ 1`. I think the latter one is too easy to overlook the wrong ones amidst a sea of correct ones.

Similarly, your `c` and `ret->name` have been allocated too short.

But, I think there is a far easier answer:

```
void concat_matrices( Matrix *A, Matrix *B, Matrix *ret ) {
        int len = strlen(A->name) + strlen(B->name) + 2 + 1; /* parens + NUL */
        ret->name = malloc(len);
        sprintf(ret->name, "(%s%s)", A->name, B->name);
        ret->R = A->R; ret->C = B->C;
        ret->dim = ret->R*ret->C;
}
```

Use `sprintf(3)` to build the string in one fell swoop. You only need to allocate one string, and that's the one you intend to *keep*, which will reduce memory fragmentation due to frequent allocate / deallocate cycles. But the most important reason for the re-write is I think this new version is easier to read. Note I broke my rule about the `+ 1` here -- clarity is improved by adding together *all* the memory required in one line.

**Update**

Your `clone_list()` function suffers from the same problem:

> ```
> Matrix *m_copy = (Matrix*)malloc(sizeof(Matrix*));
> char *c_copy = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*)*strlen(tmp->M->name));
>
> strcpy(c_copy,tmp->M->name);
> ```

Your `m_copy` looks fine, because it is a binary object and the size is known exactly. But `c_copy` is allocated one byte too short -- it is not long enough to contain the `'\0'` byte that is copied into place with the `strcpy(3)` call immediately following. This routine too is scribbling over unallocated memory.

Comment: The problem does not lie in the concat_matrices function. That works perfectly fine. Just written poorly. My issue falls inside the function clone_list inside matrix_list.h. I regret now even posting my  concat_matrices function. Please read original post more carefully, thank you.

Comment: @Matthew, once you've over-written the memory bounds in your `concat_matrices()` function, I don't think you should rely any further on the proper functioning of your program. Errors might not show themselves right away (the OS cannot enforce memory protection at the variable level), but a tool like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) _can_, and is invaluable at finding memory access errors like this. I'll give a look at your `clone_list()` -- sorry I forgot to even look at it, once I found the memory overwrite problems.

Comment: thanks for the insight, I have been using valgrind to debug. I will keep playing around but you help is still needed and much appreciated. Here is a link to the code If you want the complete source follow this link (matthewh.me/Scripts/c++/matrix_chain). Password = guest user = guest will give you read privileges to download.

Comment: The only time that valgrind reports erros is when I use this function call inside main.c. chain->release(chain_copy); chain->release(chain). If I comment those out valgrind reports 0 errors.