# Making a linked list that stores the size of the list

Tags: c, linked-list

I need to make a linked list that stores integer data. Also the list needs to know its size (the number of items in the list).

This is my code.

#### linked.h file

```
typedef struct node Node;
struct node{
int a;
Node* b;
};
Node m;

typedef struct {
node* head;
int size;
}list;
list list1;
```

#### Main file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "linked.h"
list init(list list1)
{
  list1.head = null;
  list1.size = 0;
  return list1;
}

void main()
{
list1=init(list1);
printf("%d",list1.size);
}
```

Now on running, the result is -" could not create process",
using Turbo C on Windows.

- Why am I getting this result?
- Why is the process not being created?
- Also, is this how I should initialize a linked list?

Comment: You really need to lookup some basic examples for link list and most importantly read a good C book to understand the basics.

Comment: size should be a method. Only store a value if it is a cache. Then measure the performance impact on an insert having to clear/recalculate the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors: First, you should write `Node* head;` rather than `node* head;`, and second, you should write `NULL` or `0` instead of `null`.

Probably your compiler messages are somehow suppressed.

And, yes, this is how you can initiate a linked list, but

```
list init(void)
{
    list list1;
    list1.head = null;
    list1.size = 0;
    return list1;
}
```

would be better.

And there could be made other improvements as well.

Comment: +1: Well spotted on the Node vs node and NULL vs null problems; I overlooked them.  But the code should not have been compiling with those errors...

Comment: Maybe that was what Turbo C wanted to say with "could not create process". Quite confusing...

Answer (score 0):

Your header should not define `list list1;` though it might declare it `extern list list1;`.  However, to be generally reusable, the header should not declare variables.  (See [What are extern variables in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c/).)

Your header should have multiple-inclusion guards in it.  (See [Should I use #include in headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804486/should-i-use-include-in-headers/).)

Your header should declare the functions that are provided to manipulate the lists.

You should have an implementation file that implements the list-manipulating functions (`linked.c` would be consistent with the header name `linked.h`).  The main program would then simply use those functions.

Your `main()` program should normally have the return type `int`; that is required by standard C.  Your compiler may have an alternative.

It would be nice if your types were consistently capitalized, instead of using `Node` and `list`.

Your `init()` function is poorly named.  It is also poorly designed.  You don't need both an input value and a return value.  Your code treats the passed in structure as a conveniently allocated local variable and initializes it and copies that back; it would work as well with no argument and the `list list1;` defined as a local variable.  And you should probably avoid using the same name as the global variable in the argument list (or as a local variable).  The compiler isn't confused by it; you probably are.  It would be more conventional to use:

```
static void list_init(list *new_list)
{
    new_list->head = 0;
    new_list->size = 0;
}
```

and:

```
list_init(&list1);
```

---

With all that said, there is still no obvious reason that your program won't run.

One outlandish possibility is that your `init()` function is confusing the runtime which normally runs its own function `init()`, and your initialization is not doing what the compiler expects.

Otherwise, are you able to compile and run any programs - a 'Hello World' program?  If you can compile and run programs in general, then there is something about your program that is inimical to the system - and the `init()` function takes centre stage.   If you cannot run a simple 'Hello Program', then you need to fix your compiler installation in general.