# Disable every single gcc extensions (C++)

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, c++20

The title is quite clear, is there a way to disable every single non-standard feature of gcc (extension) when compiling some C++ code. I've previously always used `-pedantic-errors` alongside `-Wall` and `-Wextra`, the first according to the gcc man page does the following

> Give an error whenever the base standard (see -Wpedantic) requires a diagnostic, in some
> equivalent to -Werror=pedantic, since there are errors enabled by this option and not
> particular library's limitations.  However, if -Wpedantic is used with -Wformat, warnings
> made into an error by -pedantic-errors.
> -Wall or -Wpedantic.

As a result it disables practically all extensions that aren't standard conforming, however. I was rather shooked that the following code compiles with gcc

```
void foo(std::vector<auto>) { ... }
```

with the `-std=c++20` flag, if we bump it down to `-std=c++17` we receive an error message prompting the use of `-std=c++20` as it's a "c++20 feature". However neither clang or msvc is willing to compile this. After some further research I was notified of the following

> This is a GCC extension and accepted by design.

Which is rather upsetting as even the safe-guards of `-pedantic-errors`, `-Wall` and `-Wextra` didn't pick this up, which leads me to question what other extensions might be silently passed through by gcc. Thus the question comes; is there any way to disable exactly every gcc extension?

**Edit**: From the comment section of [How to disable GNU C extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38939991/how-to-disable-gnu-c-extensions)

> You cannot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable GNU C extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38939991/how-to-disable-gnu-c-extensions)

Comment: TL;DR of duplicate ... You cannot.

Comment: If you want guarantees you're out of luck. All modern compilers (I've ever used) allow some non-standard features to sneak past, even with concerted effort (multiple command line options, etc) to disable them. Where I care about such things, I build with multiple different/dissimilar compilers and code analysers (and sometimes versions), each tweaked to its "most picky" mode. That increases chances of, but does not guarantee, catching dubious coding including use of non-standard features - human review has its place, no matter how much folks want toolsets to do all the heavy lifting.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a c++20 feature and the other compilers just haven't gotten around to implementing it? Usually GCC extensions require `-std=gnu++20`.

Comment: Yes I am, it's not anything standard.