# how do i disable complier extensions in code::blocks 20.03?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Currently learning C++ and I was told to disable compiler extensions, I've searched all over and have found nothing regarding disabling them for code::blocks

Comment: Which extensions?  And which compiler? (I don't know the answer to this question, but the people who do will need this information).  Also, it might not be possible anyway, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72281343/disable-every-single-gcc-extensions-c

Comment: Code::blocks does not come with compiler. You have to install a compiler separately, and then CB will use it. So, pick a compiler (gcc, clang, ...) and then research on its extensions and how to disable them.

Comment: im using g++ with code::blocks @Dialecticus

Comment: GNU extension @PaulSanders

Comment: Configure Code::Blocks for `g++` to use `-pedantic -std=c++17`