# Regarding `size_t` and the pointer types they measure

Tags: c, pointers, types, typedef

When `size_t` is undefined, it's said that the only portable way to get the definition for it is to include one of the headers that has it.

However, as I understand it, using an `#include` in a header file is bad practice, because headers shouldn't include other headers, right?

So it's the onus of the programmer to find a way to make sure a header will compile without devolving into poor programming practice.

As I understand it, the `size_t` type is the smallest type guaranteed to support the longest object your system can handle. E.g. if you run a 64-bit OS, then `size_t` should be 64 bits, because that's how RAM and pointers work in and of themselves.

As for pointers, any given pointer represents an offset from the 0th byte in RAM, where dereferencing that offset will give you the value stored at that offset. And the CPU (in this case, a 64-bit one) is given full reign to access any of the 18-quintillion-or-so bytes it is able to address with  the largest unit that it supports, a.k.a. a 64-bit integer, a.k.a. a pointer.

Thus, aren't `size_t` and any given pointer type guaranteed to be the same size?

The question, then, is which of the following would be the best practice for a given header:

```
void some_function(ptr *some_object, size_t n);
...
```

The possibilities seem to be:

```
#include <stddef.h>
// would definitely work...but including a header in a header is ugly practice

typedef long long unsigned size_t
// to account for win64 making `long` 32-bits...but it's possibly non-portable

typedef char * size_t
// I like this one...but am not 100% sure about how portable it is
```

Further, are there any reasons why using a pointer for the definition of size_t would be undesirable? It seems like it should be fine. As I understand it, a pointer is guaranteed to take up the full size of a register, and should thus be the same size as the architecture's "ideal" `size_t`

Comment: _However, as I understand it, using an #include in a header file is bad practice, because headers shouldn't include other headers, right?_

Where on earth did you hear that nonsense? Smack them for me, will you? What you shouldn't do in headers is `using namespace` at the top level (within class and function bodies it's fine though).

Comment: Btw I'm trying to close this question as it's based on a really major misunderstanding, but I don't know what exact reason that would be. Something in the off-topic category I'd guess?

Comment: @Cubic I think I remember reading it in a code review.

Comment: @Cubic Fortunately there is no `namespace` in C. :-)

Comment: The only header related things I can think of the top of my head that'd be a reasonable cause to fail a code review would be including headers that you don't actually need or _not_ including headers and instead relying on some other headers to pull these headers in.

Comment: @Cubic well, it's not off-topic. The question is about acceptable programming practice. I would personally put it under "not constructive" if I felt it was relying too much on opinion. Anyways, thanks for the information.

Comment: nested headers without include guards could be a problem.

Comment: @Cubic "...or *not* including headers and instead relying on some other headers to pull these headers in." Actually, I think that's what it was. I guess I just inferred from that that it's bad to nest headers, period. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: If you want `size_t`, include `<stddef.h>`. Period. You have way too much misinformation in your post.

Comment: I don't think it's such a bad question. The question is based on a misunderstanding, but I would upvote an answer that clears up that misunderstanding.

Comment: @rondino If you feel the need to start a discussion please do so someplace where it's appropriate (i.e not here). Also, calling on others to "accept the truth" for an unsubstantiated statement like that does reveal a kind of mindset that might have gotten you into the bad situations that you apparently need to let out on others here.

Comment: I asked a question once and they were directly downvoting it. I add "please read the question before" and it was turned to +2. Anyway I am pretty sure many users agree on that. we close the parentheses !

Comment: See [Should I use `#include` in headers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804486/should-i-use-include-in-headers/) for opinions counter to the one stated in the second paragraph.  Headers that are not self-contained and idempotent are a pain for all third parties — and tend not to be used at all.

Comment: @Meninx: Badly designed headers are a problem, but the cure is to fix the header, not to assume that headers cannot be properly designed.

Comment: i thought of the case where `A.h` is included in `B.h` and `B.h` is included in `A.h` which is of course a bad design.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's the fourth design, which I immediately ruled out as out-of-the-question because it would require other C files to at least include both `stddef.h` and `file.h` to use `file.c`'s implementation. I.e. if you're going to use the implementation from `file.c`, then you should only be required to include `file.h` and nothing more. So I agree.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> When `size_t` is undefined, it's said that the only portable way to get
>   the definition for it is to include one of the headers that has it.

Correct.

> However, as I understand it, using an `#include` in a header file is bad
>   practice, because headers shouldn't include other headers, right?

You have been misinformed. There is no reason not to include headers in other headers. Multiple `#include`s of the same header can cause problems *if* they don't have proper include guards, but the standard headers are guaranteed to have such guards (or equivalent) -- and non-standard headers *should* have such guards. (`<assert.h>` is a special case.)

If you need `size_t`, either in a source file or in a header file, then you should use `#include <stddef.h>` to make the name `size_t` visible (or you can include one of the other standard headers that also make `size_t` visible).

Including `<stddef.h>` in a header will make its declarations visible in any other files that include your header, but that's not a problem.

> As I understand it, the `size_t` type is the smallest type guaranteed
>   to support the longest object your system can handle.

It's an unsigned integer type chosen by the implementation to hold size values. It should be able to hold the size in bytes of any object (though that's not explicitly guaranteed). There's no guarantee that it's the *smallest* such type, and no benefit in assuming that it is.

> As for pointers, any given pointer represents an offset from the 0th
>   byte in RAM, where dereferencing that offset will give you the value
>   stored at that offset.
>  [...]
>  Thus, aren't size_t and any given
>   pointer type guaranteed to be the same size?

No, there is no such guarantee.  On most modern systems, pointers do represent a byte offset from *virtual* address 0, but that's not guaranteed. On a system with a segmented memory model, the maximum size of a single object might be much smaller than the size of memory; a pointer might contain a segment indicator and a byte offset, with an object not allowed to occupy more than one segment.

A value of type `size_t` needs to be able to represent the size of any single object. A pointer (say, of type `void*` or `unsigned char*`) needs to be able to represent the address of *any* object, or of any byte within it.

Don't make any unnecessary assumptions about the sizes of pointers or of `size_t`. Let the compiler figure it out for you.

> The possibilities seem to be:

```
#include <stddef.h>
// would definitely work...but including a header in a header is ugly practice
```

No, it's not ugly practice.  Just do this.

```
typedef long long unsigned size_t
// to account for win64 making `long` 32-bits...but it's possibly non-portable
```

This is absolutely non-portable. It's even possible that `size_t` could be wider than `unsigned long long`. But defining your own type that's *wider* than the compiler's `size_t` is neither useful nor necessary. And it will create a conflict if you later add a `#include` for one of the several standard headers that *correctly* define `size_t` (or for any header that includes one of those headers).

```
typedef char * size_t
// I like this one...but am not 100% sure about how portable it is
```

Absolutely not.  `size_t` is required to be an unsigned integer type.  If you've been told that integers and pointers are interchangeable, you've been badly misinformed.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks for clearing up all of the misconceptions and giving a thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If you need `size_t` you need to include `stddef.h` just as P.P. said in the comments. The definition of `size_t` in the standard:

> ISO/IEC 9899-2011 sec. 7.19 "Common definitions "
>
> `size_t`  is the unsigned integer type of the result of the sizeof operator

Furthermore the size of `size_t` is defined in the macro

> ISO/IEC 9899-2011 sec. 7.20
>   SIZE_MAX 65535

(the number 65535 is the minimum size)

So, no matter what, you need to include `stddef.h`.