# Pragma in included C file

Tags: c, struct, compiler-warnings, pragma

I have a C main file in which this .h file is included:

```
#pragma pack(1) 
 #ifndef PACKAGE
 #define PACKAGE


struct A {
  uint8_t a;
  uint8_t b;
  uint64_t c;

} typedef A;


#endif
```

After compiling the warning :

```
    myfile.c:28:10: warning: the current #pragma pack alignment value is modified in
      the included file [-Wpragma-pack]
#include "structures.h"
         ^
./structures.h:1:9: note: previous '#pragma pack' directive that modifies
      alignment is here
#pragma pack(1)
```

appears.

I don't understand what's wrong in my code. Is there any way to delete this warning ?

Here is a complete example :

This is a simple C file called "myfile.c" :

```
#include "structures.h"
int main(){
  return 0;
}
```

And this is the .h file called "structures.h" :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

  #pragma pack(1)
 #ifndef PACKAGE
 #define PACKAGE


struct A {
  uint8_t a;
  uint8_t b;
  uint64_t c;

} typedef A;


#endif
```

And the warning is :

```
myfile.c:2:10: warning: the current #pragma pack alignment value is modified in
      the included file [-Wpragma-pack]
#include "structures.h"
         ^
./structures.h:5:11: note: previous '#pragma pack' directive that modifies
      alignment is here
  #pragma pack(1)
          ^
1 warning generated.
```

Comment: There should be another message before that which explains what the problem is. The message you pasted here is diagnostic information, not the error message

Comment: I just edited my post with the full error message.

Comment: Can you include an example? i.e. give us something we can run to reproduce this error

Comment: I edited my post including an example.

Comment: Which header did you show?  `package.h`?   So `structures.h` is a separate header that also contains a `#pragma pack` directive, possibly with a different alignment?

Comment: It is warning that the header file changed the packing and forgot to change it back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you need to read the GCC manual on pragmas — [§6.61.10 Structure-Layout Pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.3.0/gcc/Structure-Layout-Pragmas.html#Structure-Layout-Pragmas).  You could sensibly use:

```
#ifndef PACKAGE
#define PACKAGE

#pragma pack(push, 1) 

typedef struct A {
  uint8_t a;
  uint8_t b;
  uint64_t c;
} A;

#pragma pack(pop) 

#endif /* PACKAGE */
```

I don't know whether this works with all the compilers that are relevant to you.

Incidentally, I moved the `typedef` keyword to the start.  The C grammar treats `typedef` as a [storage class](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.1), and also stipulates (C11 [§6.11.5 Storage class specifiers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.11.5)) that the *placement of a storage-class specifier other than at the beginning of the declaration specifiers in a declaration is an obsolescent feature*.  Put the keyword `typedef` first!

I also note that this header is not self-contained (though it is idempotent because of the header guards).  It relies on `<stdint.h>` (or perhaps `<inttypes.h>`) having been included already.  Ideally, you should add `#include <stdint.h>` before the first `#pragma` so that the code will compile even if this is the first header included in a translation unit.  See also [Should I use `#include` inside headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804486/should-i-use-include-in-headers)

Comment: Chuckling... just fixing the `typedef` allowed his original to compile on gcc.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin — Hmmmm…that never occurred to me as a possibility.  I've not sent the code past a compiler, neither the original nor my response. If moving the `typedef` around 'fixes' the original, then a wry chuckle of mild disbelief is in order.

Comment: I did move the other includes and `#pragma pack(1)` inside the `PACKAGE` header guard, but other than that, I ran it with `-Wall -Extra -pedantic` and gcc was happy with it. (also added a declaration `A a = { .a = 1, .b = 2, .c = 0xdeadbeef };` and `printf ("a.c 0x%" PRIx64 "\n", a.c);` just to make sure everything wasn't optimized out). gcc likes your solution equally well.