# C how to use library with multiple header tree

Tags: c, compilation, static-libraries

I am not understanding how I should compile with gcc the following .c and library.

example:

Files: `"commons.h"` and `"commons.c"` (the .c defines function etc...)

Files: `"level1.h"` and `"level1.c"`, `level1.c` includes `"commons.h"`

Files: `"level2.h"` and `"level2.c"`, `level2.c` includes `"commons.h"` and `"level1.h"`

I tried this and got "undefined reference to  x" (where x is a function inside level1):

```
gcc commons.c -c -o commons.o    (OK)
gcc level1.c -c -o level1.o      (OK)
gcc level2.c -o level2.o   (error, undefined reference to x)
```

I expect to have level2 to be execute, I will only execute this.

How should I compile? Which order? (an example with command line will help me understand)

Comment: @uneven_mark Should I create a library everytime? ar rvs--- with commons, then do it again with level1 and again with level2?

Comment: @uneven_mark if you could post the shell command to compile these files correctly I will understand and mark the solution. I am a little bit lost

Comment: Are `commons`, `level1` and `level2` supposed to be compiled into one static/dynamic library, one executable, or multiple libraries?

Comment: @uneven_mark all the files will be used for just one executable, which is level2

Comment: `gcc commons.c level1.c level2.c -o my_executable` does not work?

Comment: @uneven_mark maybe I or you missunderstood, I edited the post

Comment: Your last line of the edit has a typo, `-c` is missing. Afterwards you call `gcc common.o level1.o level2.o -o my_executable` to link the object files to an executable.

Comment: @uneven_mark this isn't a typo, level2 contains the main(). I have error when I try to compile level2 which is the source code of the "real" executable

Comment: Presumably, `level1.c` includes `level1.h` to ensure that the features declared in `level1.h` match those defined in `level1.c`, and similarly with `level2.c` and `level2.h`.  If those implementation files do not include the corresponding headers, your naming conventions or your coding conventions (or both) leave much to be desired.  See also [Should I use `#include` in headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1804719/15168)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last line should also use the `-c` flag in order to compile `level2.c` to an object file `level2.o`.

Afterwards the object files should be linked to create an executable, which is done via

```
gcc common.o level1.o level2.o -o my_executable
```

Alternatively you can directly supply all the source files to `gcc` without the `-c` flag, in which case it will perform all of the compilation and linking steps at once:

```
gcc common.c level1.c level2.c -o my_executable
```

Your error is currently caused, because you are instructing `gcc` without the `-c` option to compile and link the source file `level2.c` alone, but of course it can not be linked alone as it is missing symbols from the other source files.

The fact that `level2.c` contains `main` does not change anything about this. `main` is handled like any other function, only that it has a special meaning in the final executable as entry point.

Comment: I completely missunderstood "linking" and "library". Solved, marked as solution.